# Validating a null link in HTML

Tags: html

Is this valid HTML?

```
<a href="#" id="whatever">Home</a>
```

I'm using the ID to call a jQuery function with an id of "whatever."  I can't find anything that says whether this is valid.  I'm having a debate as to whether it is.

Also, is it valid HTML to have a radio button group without one selected?

Comment: I think something different is being asked there.  I want to know if the # (null) is okay for the `href`

Comment: The link has text, unlike the link in the other question.

Comment: You should ask the question about radio buttons separately, after checking whether earlier questions on that exist. You should ask separate questions separately for many reasons, including the fact that a multi-question cannot have a title that describes all the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is completely valid.

Just as a suggestion, your jQuery function should prevent the default behavior of your anchor tag:

```
jQuery("#whatever").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default anchor tag behavior

    // Do what you need here
});
```

This way you will prevent the common "scroll-to-top" behavior when using `href="#"`.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thank you.

Comment: @sehummel If you're going to prevent the default behaviour, you don't need anything in the href attribute, it can just be empty.  Using a "#" href value prevents the link from causing a HTTP request if JavaScript is not working, but if that scenario was a concern, the links would be written to fail over to HTTP requests anyway.

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski according to the HTML5 draft (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#hyperlink), not using the `href` attribute is valid, but it doesn't create an hyperlink: 'The href attribute on a and area elements is not required; when those elements do not have href attributes they do not create hyperlinks'.

Comment: Yes, but no href is not the same as having an empty href, an empty href is a valid relative URI, e.g. if the current URI is `/products/alarmclock.html`, an empty href will request `/products/`.

Comment: I didn't know that. I was almost sure that the empty href is a relative URI to the same document. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, one might have thought that because that's what an empty (or absent) form action does!

Answer (score 1):

It's valid, and necessary to have *something* in the href attribute in most browsers to activate the link behaviour of the `<a>` element.  (although `href=""` would cause the browser to open the index page of the current 'folder'.)

IF the link represents some change of state, then it's better to put more (e.g. '#home') so if the user presses back/forward/refresh, you can restore the state on page load - this is a boon during development too if you tend to refresh the pages a lot whilst developing them.

--

Unselected radio groups are trickier, HTML 4 validators will let it pass, but the HTML 4 specification says one must always be checked (*Since user agent behavior differs, authors should ensure that in each set of radio buttons that one is initially "on".*).  HTML 5 has relaxed this as far as I know since I cannot find any equivalent wording in the HTML 5 specification.

However, such a group of radio buttons is in an invalid state, so it should not be used for capturing optional input (if the user checks one, they cannot uncheck it).

It's better for the user if a default value was selected (usually the most frequent choice), or if it is optional, to have an explicit option for null (e.g. 'None of the above')

Answer (score 0):

The HTML markup is valid and conforms to HTML specifications, which cite URI specifications regarding the values of the `href` attribute. The current authoritative specification is [RFC 3986](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc3986), *Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax*, also known as Internet-standard STD 66. According to it, as well as older URI specifications, `#` is a same-document reference. The relevant clauses in the spec are 3.5 and 4.4.

Following a link with `href="#"` thus means staying in the current document, with no reload, but positioning the document at its start (“jump to the start”). Thus, it is not a no-op as such, even though `href="#"` has been used to make the element a fake link, more or less.

On the other hand, an `a` element without any `href` attribute is valid, too. It will then not be regarded as a link in visual renderings, scripting, link analysis, etc. If it’s not meant to be a link, don’t make it a link.